# How to check if Backbone view exists?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following situation:
 - I initialize VIEW_1 on Application startup.
 - VIEW1 Render function loads VIEW2.
 - on menu CLICK event in VIEW2 i render VIEW3.

The problem is that, when click event happens, it always initializes VIEW3 with another ID which means that i have a GHOST VIEW situation.

any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't instantiate view3 in the click handler. Instantiate it beforehand (in view2 init or render?) and update view3 on click.

Comment: Thank you Gijsjan for your reply.
I resolved my problem using factory metod to check weather the view exists when i initialize the view.